# ClassA extends ClassB<ClassC>

Tags: java, generics

```
ClassA extends ClassB<ClassC>
```

Собственно говоря, помогите разобраться (вопрос выше). 
С generic типами для конструкторов, полей и методов - все понятно.
Но до сих пор загадкой остается конструкция описанная выше. 
Абсолютно не понимаю:
 `extends ClassB<ClassC>` 
понятен: 
 `extends ClassB`

Желательно, с примером, на банальных вещах: машины, продукты или т.п
Спасибо

Comment: А в чем разница `ClassB<ClassC>` или к примеру `ClassB<Integer>` ? Вроде никакой

Comment: На сколько я разобрался, класс ClassC из примера, тоже должен быть Generic : ClassC<M> к примеру.

Comment: Что за пример? Откуда пример? Почему его видите вы, но не видит никто здесь присутствующий? Может стоить привести и его и от него как-то отталкиваться?  Да вроде класс `B` только дженерик `class ClassB<T>` или возможно `class ClassB<T extends ClassC>`... о том, что `ClassC` - дженерик - ничто не свидетельствует

Comment: @АлексейШиманский пример из головы. И скорее всего довольно бесполезный. Если бы понимал о чем пишу, пример был бы лучше

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, вроде разобрался. Если у нас есть ClassA extends ClassB<ClassC>, то ClassA classA = new ClassA(); ClassD classD = new ClassD(); classA.putSome(classD) работать не будет. А если ClassC classC = new ClassC(); classA.putSome(classC) - будет работать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClassA extends ClassB<ClassC>
```

`ClassA` наследуется от класса `ClassB`, последний в свою очередь параметризован типом `ClassC`.

Пример из [jdk](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

У тебя есть класс `ArrayList<T>`, который параметризован каким-то типом `T`. Далее, тебе нужен свой класс `MySuperArrayList`, который будет наследоваться от `ArrayList`, причем класс `MySyperArrayList` должен работать с типом `MySuperType`.

Тогда реализация твоего класса будет выглядеть следующим образом

```
public class MySuperArrayList extends ArrayList<MySuperType>
{ ... }
```